# What do I do when both answers are right and fantastic?

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Protocol when one question has 2 correct answers?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/903/protocol-when-one-question-has-2-correct-answers)

Pertaining to this question, [How are Portal and "Black Mesa" related?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20667/how-are-portal-and-black-mesa-related).

As you can see both answers are valid, accurate, and awesome. One is more concise, while the other uses a site to validate the claims? Who gets the check and the 10 points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a variety of things. Most importantly, keep in mind that you can always upvote both answers! Keep in mind, the point of acceptance is to indicate the answer that you, the author of the question, found most helpful and/or conclusive to the problem you had. Also take a gander at [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/903/protocol-when-one-question-has-2-correct-answers), which dealt with a scenario where there were two answers that had different applications.

1. Analyze the two and decide whether you liked the conciseness more, or the greater detail more. Pick the one you think was most useful in answering your own query.
2. Pick the answer that sounds more interesting to you. Did one have a cooler detail than the other?
3. Pick the one that came first, if that's your thing.
4. Flip a coin.
5. Accept one, and upvote the other. This spreads a difference of only 5 reputation. As far as which one to pick, see 1-4.

Comment: How sad, so if they both are valid, offer unique information while answering the question, both are interesting... I'm only down to flipping a coin or picking the first diver (even if it is because he or she is a faster typist then the other). So no other option...

Comment: Not *that* sad - could be worse. I have a question about Eve Online that only has two Answers - both totally *wrong*...

Comment: Yep, now that is sad!

Comment: or, just upvote both and don't accept. It's not required.