# How should I handle multiple helpful but incomplete answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette

On *[Is there a reason to complete additional research tasks after a Pokédex entry is completed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/395815/181240)*, I received multiple helpful answers from different users. In particular, [Wondercricket](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/395816/3) and [Joe's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/395817/181240) answers provided two different but valid reasons to complete additional tasks.

Both are equally valid answers, but they feel like two halves of a single complete answer. This makes it difficult to decide which one to accept. What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Related: [Protocol when one question has 2 correct answers?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/903/28182),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there were multiple correct answers posted and choosing one of them would serve difficult, this seems like a good case for a community wiki with all of the collected information.

With that said, I converted the answer I submitted to a community wiki and referenced the answers Joe and Pinkerman posted

Comment: I would say the same. If both answers have elements of the answer, but not are the full answer, I would say 1- comment so that if they want, the answerers could complete their answer and give them the check or 2- if no edit were made to the answer or its been a while, answer your own question with the full answer.

Answer (score 4):

Based on a quick look, I would instead say that that question has two *complete* answers. Each of the answers completely describes a different "reason to keep completing a Pokémon's research tasks after its Pokédex entry has been completed", which is what the question requests.

If one of those reasons is more useful than the other to you personally, you can accept that one. You can also choose not to accept any of the answers.

Comment: It might be counter intuitive, but another option might be to create a community wiki with all the collected information and the OP accept that one. That is what I did with [What is the maximum power level in Destiny 2, and how do I get there?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/378259/124566). As new expansions and updates came out, users would either update old answers or submit new ones

Comment: @Wondercricket I think this should be an answer.